# Using C++ in the GNU/Linux world

Tags: linux, c++

As a C++ developer working with embedded systems, it's very difficult for me to stay in the C++ "mindset" when working regularly with Linux APIs. For example, I may wish to use libudev, which uses polling for monitoring device connections/disconnections, makes use of a context for state and generally uses patterns which could be quite nicely expressed using the C++ Standard Library.

I also often feel myself straying into the C territory when performing trivial tasks such as checking for a file's existence using `stat`. **C++17 now has `std::filesystem`**.

I also simply don't have time to write C -> C++ bindings for every GNU/Linux subsystem I might want to interact with, simply for the case of code clarity and "completeness." Most of these userspace interfaces are *very* mature by this point, and I don't think it's too ambitious to expect bindings for C++ to exist and be maintained. To put my case from earlier into perspective, Python even has `pyudev`, which provides a lovely abstraction around libudev.

I suppose my question is therefore:

How can I keep my C++ code clean and expressive (maintaining C++ philosophy) while programming in a GNU/Linux environment without writing hacky bindings for almost everything?

Comment: It is a very interesting question but it is off topic for this site, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one just uses the C API in C++.

You can try seeing if anyone else has created a C++ interface which is more object-oriented. For instance, the first result for Googling "udev C++" is the GitHub repository [dimitry-ishenko/udev](https://github.com/dimitry-ishenko/udev), which might be helpful (I can't vouch for it). You can also interact with udev using a C++ D-Bus implementation, such as [sdbus-c++](https://github.com/Kistler-Group/sdbus-cpp).

[Boost](https://www.boost.org/) is a major source of additional "semistandard" C++ libraries, which may cover some of the gaps in C++-style interfaces to the standard POSIX libraries. For example, the filesystem library was in Boost before it was adopted in C++17. [Boost.Interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/interprocess/) deals with shared memory, mmap, etc. [Boost.Process](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/process/), [Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/program_options/), and [Boost.Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/asio/) also cover some POSIX territory.

Comment: Thanks for the link to sdbus-c++, I'll investigate that.

Comment: Unfortunately, udev communicates over netlink IPC, not dbus, so your proposed solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of the HAL days. Now it seems you can use D-Bus to talk to udisks, upower, or NetworkManager. My impression is that the kernel communicates with udev over netlink, but it's not a way user applications can talk to it.